# how to resolve the errors coming in jspx file

Tags: spring-roo

I created project through spring too. After that i added one table and create model, controller and view. in View `show.jspx` is when i run it, i got error in browser console that `"Empty string passed to getElementById()"`.

Here is my `show.jspx`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div class="mainbar" xmlns:spform="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" xmlns:form="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form" xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/util" xmlns:table="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form/fields" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" xmlns:field="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form/fields" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:page="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <c:set var="canCreate" value="false" />
    <c:set var="canUpdate" value="false" />
    <c:set var="canDelete" value="false" />
    <c:set var="canList" value="true" />
    <c:if test="${not empty privilege and privilege eq 'ROLE_ADMIN'}">
        <c:set var="canCreate" value="true" />
        <c:set var="canDelete" value="true" />
        <c:set var="canUpdate" value="true" />
    </c:if>

    <c:set var="tab" value="${param.tab}"/>
     <page:tabs id="i_selectaccount_list"> 
            <field:tabitem tabId="selectAccountDetails" isActive="${empty tab or tab eq 0}" id="t_selectaccount_selectaccounts_new_label"> 
        <page:show_in_list id="ps_com_softtrends_mboutique_model_selectaccount" object="${selectaccounts}" path="/selectaccounts" z="" 
        create="${canCreate}" update="${canUpdate}" delete="${canDelete}" list="${canList}" 
        displayTitle="false">
            <c:if test="${not empty privilege and privilege eq 'ROLE_ADMIN'}">
                    <field:display_in_table field="selectAccountName" 
                    id="ps_com_softtrends_mboutique_model_selectaccount_selectaccountname" 
                    object="${Selectaccount.selectAccountId}" z=""/>
            </c:if> 
             <field:display_in_table field="selectAccountName" 
            id="ps_com_softtrends_mboutique_model_selectaccount_selectaccountid" 
            object="${selectaccount.selectAccountId}" z=""/> 
        </page:show_in_list>
    </field:tabitem> 
            <spring:message code="label_com_softtrends_mboutique_model_selectaccount_selectaccountname" var=""/>
            <util:panel id="" title="" openPane="false"/> 
                <div class="widget-content">
                <table:table data="${existingselectaccount}" id="l_com_softtrends_mboutique_model_selectaccount" path="/selectaccounts/deleteSelectAccount/${selectAccountId}" typeIdFieldName="SelectAccountId"
                    create="false" update="true" delete="true" show="false"
                    addParamPage="tab" addParamValPage="0">
                    <table:column id="c_com_softtrends_mboutique_model_selectaccount_selectaccountname" property="selectaccount" maxLength="-1"/>
                </table:table>
                </div>
         </page:tabs>   
    </div>
```

Here is my controller show method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{selectAccountId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String show(@PathVariable("selectAccountId") Integer selectAccountId, Model uiModel) {
         uiModel.addAttribute("selectaccount", Selectaccount.findSelectaccount(selectAccountId)/*.getSelectAccountName()*/);
        uiModel.addAttribute("itemId", selectAccountId);
        return "selectaccounts/show";
    }
```

This is model class method:

```
public static long countSelectaccounts() {
        return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT COUNT(o) FROM Selectaccount o", Long.class).getSingleResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
<util:panel id="" title="" openPane="false"/>
```

fill the empty attributes: the `id` and `title` are required.

Comment: try to comment blocks of the jpsx code to locate which tag contains the problem. I notice that you are using your owns tagxs. Also, you can try to identify the line/tagx file of the error by the stack trace (it doesn't say the exact line but can give you a clue). Good luck!

Comment: <field:display_in_table field="selectAccountName" 
                    id="ps_com_softtrends_mboutique_model_selectaccount_selectaccountname" 
                    object="${Selectaccount.selectAccountId}" z=""/>

Comment: error may be in these lines..because on brawser console log it is showing  Empty string is passing ..getElementById()